# Consultar total consumido por mes y mostrar saldo anterior consumido si lo tiene

Tags: php, base-de-datos

No soy muy experto pero trato de salir siempre, comento trabajo en php y una bd mysql:

Ejemplo tengo 3 tablas:

```
**Trabajos          pedidos         detalle_pedido**
id_trabajos      id_pedidos       id_detalle 
cliente          tipo_ped         id_pedido 
...              fecha_retiro     cantidad
                                  valor_unit
```

Vinculando las tablas necesito obtener el siguiente resultado:

```
trabajo N°    saldo pedidos anteriores    pedidos en el mes    total
OT 1                   2500                       1200          3700
OT 2                      0                       1200          1200
OT 3                   6500                          0          6500
```

Probé esto pero me da solo el total que lleva cada OT, como llamo a las q han ocupado algo el mes consultado

```
  SELECT tj.id_trabajos, pm.id_trabajo, pm.id_pedido, 
                      pm.fecha_retiro, dp.id_pedido,   
                      SUM(dp.cantidad * dp.valor_unit) AS total
                         FROM trabajos tj
                             INNER JOIN pedido_mate pm ON tj.id_trabajos=pm.id_trabajo 
                             INNER JOIN detall_pedimento dp ON pm.id_pedido = dp.id_pedido 
                             WHERE  pm.estado = 'E'
                             GROUP BY id_trabajos"
```

y esta otra me da solo lo del mes

```
 if(isset($_GET['mes'])){$mes=$_GET['mes'];
 $consulta_mysql="SELECT trabajos.id_trabajos, pedido_mate.id_trabajo, pedido_mate.id_pedido, pedido_mate.fecha_retiro, detall_pedimento.id_pedido,   SUM(detall_pedimento.cantidad * detall_pedimento.valor_unit) AS total
            FROM trabajos
           INNER JOIN pedido_mate ON trabajos.id_trabajos=pedido_mate.id_trabajo 
INNER JOIN detall_pedimento ON pedido_mate.id_pedido = detall_pedimento.id_pedido 
WHERE MONTH(pedido_mate.fecha_retiro)= '$mes' AND trabajos.area = 'Facturacion'  GROUP BY id_trabajos";
 $resultado_consulta_mysql=mysql_query($consulta_mysql,$conexion);
  }else{echo "No se pasaron datos en el GET";}
```

Probé pero solo consigo lo del mes y no el saldo anterior..
agradecería mucho orientación y como resolver este caso...quedo muy atento a todos los comentarios...

Comment: Hola Carlos! Bienvenido a [es.so] te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para ver el funcionamiento del sitio y ganar tu primera medalla! Por otro lado, nos vendría muy bien ver que has intentado para poder ayudarte con el problema concreto.

Comment: Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP. El código compartido no solo es potencialmente vulnerable a este tipo de ataques, sino que además utiliza extensiones (mysql_\*) que ya no están soportadas y que se eliminaron del estándar PHP. Deberías usar mysqli_\* o PDO en su lugar.